# Write a Model Class in CodeIgniter with ORM style

Tags: php, codeigniter

I thought about using an actual ORM like Doctrine, then I figured its download link was even broken...and all tutorials online dated back to 2011. Also I'll have to write yaml files.

Then I start off by trying to write my own model class in ORM style.

I just fill it up with fields and save it to database, which is easy.

But I encounter a problem trying to retrieve data from database.

```
class User extends CI_Model {

    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $displayName;

 public function save() {
  .....
 }

public function search_by_email($email) {
    $user = new User();
    $this->db->select('email')->from('user')->where('email', $email);
    $result = $this->db->get();
    if ($result->num_rows()==0) {
        return false;
    }else {
        foreach ($result->result() as $field) {

        }
    }
}
```

I know normally in CodeIgniter, you return `$query->result()`, well as ORM custom, I'm trying to return an object...Is there a way to do this? What function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`result`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) takes a string that represents a class that it will instantiate and assigned the result data (each field as a property of the object):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users;");

foreach ($query->result('User') as $row)
{
   echo $row->name; // call attributes
   echo $row->reverse_name(); // or methods defined on the 'User' class
}
```

---

regarding your comment, i'm pretty sure that [codeigniter has no idea about anything regarding the class](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_result.php#L199) you pass to the `result` method.  It looks like it just instantiates it and sets property and valuefor each column/value returned from the db:

```
$this->custom_result_object[$class_name][$i] = new $class_name();

foreach ($this->{$_data}[$i] as $key => $value)
{
    $this->custom_result_object[$class_name][$i]->$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this before. Quick question: does CodeIgniter read my pre-established User class with fields and populate these fields with $query result? How does CodeIgniter know which database field corresponds to the fields inside my class?

Answer (score 0):

One ORM that works quite well with codeIgniter is [php-activerecord](http://getsparks.org/packages/php-activerecord/versions/HEAD/show) which is based off the rails active record model.

The function your trying to copy "search_by_email" is done through a

```
Late static binding method.
```

So you might see functions that are called like so:

```
Object::find_by_email()

Object::search_by_email()
```

Comment: Can you successfully install this through Sparks? It seems mine is not working (after installation...)

Comment: I actually tried pretty hard to get php-activerecord work...I used Spark to install and load it from autoload "$autoload['sparks'] = array('php-activerecord/0.0.2');" and try to test if it works with    "echo '<pre>'; var_dump(Test::all()); exit;" Nothing shows on my page (Yes I have created a Test Model file)

Comment: Did you include the loader file in    core/

Comment: It works now! Not very much up to my imagination-I still have to create database tables manually but thank you for help.